# R: Error in Validate() : All GA queries must have title parameters

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Code:

```
library(httr)
library(RGoogleAnalyticsPremium)
client.id <- "xxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client.secret <- "ttttttttt"
token <- Auth(client.id, client.secret)
save(token,file="./token_file")
ValidateToken(token)
query.pv.list_2018 <- Init(start.date = "2018-07-20",
                           end.date = "2018-07-23",
                           dimensions = "ga:date,ga:medium,ga:sourceMedium,ga:pagePathLevel1,ga:pagePath",
                           metrics = "ga:pageviews",
                           filters = "ga:pagePathLevel1==/car/")
ga.pv.query_2018 <- QueryBuilder(query.pv.list_2018)
x <- GetFile(ga.pv.query_2018, token, "1111111", "UA-233455-8", "44444")
```

In R's newest version, I can only use library "RGoogleAnalyticsPremium" instead of "RGoogleAnalytics". Since it's not working with **web application**, and I couldn't find **installed application**, I used **others**. I got an error when I ran the last code, it said,

```
Error in Validate() : All GA queries must have title parameters.
```

Does anyone know what's the solution of this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the title? Maybe this is doing some kind of unsampled report request, these are the ones that have a title if I remember correctly?

Comment: @Eduardo I added the title, but don't know what I should put in title, had no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'title' is the title of the unsampled report. 'Unsampled Report' is [part of Google Analytics 360.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2601061?hl=en)

If you do have Google Analytics 360, you need to generate that report, it can take some time to generate that. 
You can read in the official documentation as to how to generate the report [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2601061?hl=en)

Once it shows 'completed' you can then try to use the same query with 'title' in your generated report.

Comment: I don't have Google Analytics 360, mine is a free version. But then how can I extract data from GA since the newest R version cannot install **RGoogleAnalytics** but **RGoogleAnalyticsPremium**? Your info above is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Lara19 You would have to install the older version of R to use it or contact these guys - Tatvic https://github.com/Tatvic to help you out because they are managing the package at the moment & I don't think it has been updated for the latest version. Best case would be use GA API to dump the data in a DB and then access it using R.